# Pass value to Pojo Auto Complete from backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete, converters

I have tried the Pojo autocomplete component from [Primefaces Samples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml). I could able to query the data with help of converter attached and could able to get the selected value as pojo (id="sm123", name="jerith", age=22) at Backing bean for business process, but the problem is how do i set the value to pojo autocomplete when i get `id` alone instead of complete pojo. So with retrieved `id` alone is it possible to covert it back into pojo using the same Coverter attached to autocomplete component.

Comment: Can your provide your code please?

Comment: @QueryLars, my approach is same as the primefaces pojo sample (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml), instead of `ThemeConvertor` am using my own, for instance lets take the PrimeFaces Example, if i got only the id of theme how can convert into Theme object when setting from backing bean.